# Datepicker Set End Date Autofill

Tags: jquery, drupal, datepicker

I am writing a booking events module, and have the following in my JS file to manage a start and end date...

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.rooms_datepicker = {
  attach: function(context) {

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      beforeShow: function() {

        instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
        if (instance.settings.startDateSelector !== undefined) {
          startDate = $(instance.settings.startDateSelector).val();
          format = instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
          if (startDate !== undefined && startDate !== '') {
            var $date = $.datepicker.parseDate(format, startDate, instance.settings);
            $(this).datepicker({
                minDate: $date,
                onSelect: function(){
                    var eventDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(eventDate.getTime()));
                    eventDate.setDate(eventDate.getDate()+1); 
                    $(this).datepicker("setDate", eventDate);
                }
            });
          }
        }



      }
    });
  }
};


})(jQuery);
```

Its ended up getting a bit messy, but the first bit works, and the date format is retrieved perfectly. Once a start date is selected, a min date is provided for the end date.

**The bit that isn't working is the auto fill of the end date to be +1day from the selected Start Date.**

I've been looking at this for a bit too long, and I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can point out what stupid mistake I'm making!

Answer (score 0):

mistake is `eventDate` getting value form start_date and `+1 date added` then you put back to `$(this)==>$("#start_date")` that is problem you `setDate` to in end_date datepicker.

```
    var eventDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    eventDate.setDate(eventDate.getDate()+1); 
    $("#end_date").datepicker("setDate", eventDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working properly. I replaced #end_date with the ID of the text input, but its doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I have had to change the JS quite a bit from the original question to get the autofill to work, but have managed to get it working. The only problem now is an error when the form is not on the page, as the JS is applied to all pages. I need to figure out a way to only run the script on pages with the datepicker enabled form. http://jsfiddle.net/gXQ2q/